# multiDexEnabled true VS minSdkVersion 21

Tags: android, android-sdk

При компмляции проекта с подключенными google-play-services и google-maps библиотеками gradle выдаёт

```
Consider using to minSdkversion 21 or multiDexEnabled true
```

Пробовал подключить `multiDex` и в конфиг добавить эту строку, но все равно ничего не получилось. Как быть?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проверьте подключение.

Multidex подключается в двух местах: директива в build.gradle

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ....
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

и наследование вашего класса Application от `MultiDexApplication`. Если вы Application переопределяли, то смените в классе вашего приложения родительский класс на `MultiDexApplication`. Если нет - то добавьте в `AndroidManifest.xml` тэгу `<application>` параметр

```
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

Answer (score 1):

Значит неправильно подключаете `multiDex`. В андроид версиях ниже 21 код исполняет **dalvik**. У нее есть особенность в том, что количество методов в dex файле не должно привышать чуть более 65 000 методов. С 21 апи, код выполняется с помошью **ART**. Там такой особенности нет.

Для того, чтобы подключить `multiDex` необходимо: [инструкция](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

Comment: В итоге в apk будет 2 classes.dex?

Comment: Для dalvik да. Проект будет дольше собираться правда

Comment: можно попробовать minifyEnabled true. Proguard обрезает неиспользуемые методы и мультидекс может не понадобиться

Comment: Да, это хороший совет. Единственное, его надо включать на начальной стадии проекта, а то можно засесть с исправление ошибок на долго)))

Comment: @pavel163 Да не, с Proguard'ом нынче все достаточно ровно, не то, что раньше. Я сам удивился. http://jollydroid.ru/notebook/2016-12-29-ProGuard-1